# SQL query to get object names in Enterprise Architect diagram

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I want an SQL query to get the list of object names in a specific diagram of Enterprise Architect.

My target Diagram_ID is 184

Elements are stored in `t_object` and diagram objects (the graphical representation of one element in one diagram) in `t_diagramobjects`. An entry in `t_diagramobjects` has a reference to the diagram (`Diagram_ID`) and to the element being displayed (`Object_ID`).

- `t_object table`: has columns `Object_ID` `and Name`
- `t_diagramobjects` table: has columns `Object_ID` and `Diagram_ID`

If I do:

> select Object_ID from t_diagramobjects where Diagram_ID=184

I get the list of `Object_ID`s but I need the names. I want a query involving `t_object` table to get the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Rereading your question, seems like you do not know about **join**.

Here is a link (Assuming SQL Server again): https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

---

**Another EDIT**

Here is more detail about why a normal `join` does not work.

You can have your ea project in the form of a local file or in a database. When stored in a local file, it is stored as a MS Access database. MS Access does not support the `join` keyword alone, you need to put either `inner join`, `outer join`, `left join`, `right join`...

And for those that do not know, you can run SQL queries in a local file project by creating a new search as a SQL Query.

### [image]

Diagram Objects represent the Visual elements you see on the diagrams.
The table t_object contains the elements in the repository, so you can make a simple join with the OBJECT_ID column.

This query should work on  an access database (.eap file) as well as on a SQL Server database:

```
select o.name from t_object o
inner join t_diagramobjects do
on do.Object_ID=o.Object_ID
where do.Diagram_ID=184
```

Comment: You can also do subqueries, but a join is way simpler in this case

Comment: I knew a bit about joins but I did not manage to get a working join query. Your query is one the first I tried but it fails with "Syntax error in FROM clause". I am using "SQL Scratch Pad" inside "Enterprise Architect".

Comment: @Robert is your project on a database or do you open it as a local file?

Comment: @robert try with inner join instead of join, updated my answer